# Can't Access CheckListBox by FindControl in FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I have form view and formview_databound() method like this:

```
 <asp:FormView ID="frm" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="dsSelectedProduct">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:BulletedList ID="blstCatlist"  DataTextField="Name"  DataValueField="Id" runat="server"></asp:BulletedList>
     </itemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>
```

and

```
if (frm.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnl
{
   var blstCatlist = frm.FindControl("blstCatlist") as BulletedList;
}
```

but `blsCatlist` is `null`. 
I'm really Confused! because **can** find it in **formview_Inserting()** event but on ChangingMode and changedMode cant find it and reference is null.

Actually I wanna bind a bulletList in ItemTemplate and a CheckBoxList in EditTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.

To find a control when you do not know its immediate container you need a custom method that searches the controls in a hierarchy of controls.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control rootControl, string controlID)
{
    if (rootControl.ID == controlID) return rootControl;

    foreach (Control controlToSearch in rootControl.Controls)
    {
        Control controlToReturn = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID);
        if (controlToReturn != null) return controlToReturn;
    }
    return null;
}
```

`FindControl` on a `FormView` will only work for the template that the FormView's "CurrentMode" property is set to.

In your case, you can only do FindControl for "BulletedList" if your FormView is set to read-only mode., since that's the template that your control exists in.

Comment: dear @giammin,  i know that. it doesn't work. i utulize your solution

Comment: @Edalat anyway your control is not in the template for insertmode